# Pandas - append strings in data frame: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Tags: python, string, pandas, indexing, dataframe

I have a data.frame looking similar to this (except much longer and with way more colornames):

```
ff = pd.DataFrame({'OldCol':['darkbrown','lightbeige','lightbrown / beige','beige','brown','beige / cognac'], 'NewCol':['nan','nan','nan','nan','nan','nan']})
```

I want the data.frame to look like this:

```
ffnew = pd.DataFrame({'OldCol':['darkbrown','lightbeige','lightbrown / beige','beige','brown','beige / cognac'], 'NewCol':['brown','beige','beige / brown','sand','brown','sand / brown']})
```

I tried the following:

```
ff.loc[ff['OldCol'].str.contains(r'brown|cognac',na=False) & ff['NewCol'].str.contains(r'nan'), 'NewCol'] = 'brown'
ff.loc[ff['OldCol'].str.contains(r'brown|cognac',na=False) & ~ff['NewCol'].str.contains(r'nan|brown'), 'NewCol'] = ff['NewCol']+'/ brown'

ff.loc[ff['OldCol'].str.contains(r'beige|sand',na=False) & ff['NewCol'].str.contains(r'nan'), 'NewCol'] = 'beige'
ff.loc[ff['OldCol'].str.contains(r'beige|sand',na=False) & ~ff['NewCol'].str.contains(r'nan|beige'), 'NewCol'] = ff['NewCol'] +'/ beige'
```

In my longer data.frame I typically get the error:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis

Can anyone help?
Thanks very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem with duplicates in `index`. You can replace all values of index by [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) to `Regular Index` (`0,1,2..len(df)-1`). Old values are removed by parameter `drop=True`:

```
ff.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Test:

```
ff = pd.DataFrame({'OldCol':['darkbrown','lightbeige','lightbrown / beige','beige','brown','beige / cognac'], 'NewCol':['nan','nan','nan','nan','nan','nan']})
ffnew = pd.DataFrame({'OldCol':['darkbrown','lightbeige','lightbrown / beige','beige','brown','beige / cognac'], 'NewCol':['brown','beige','beige / brown','sand','brown','sand / brown']})
ff.index = [0,0,2,3,4,5]
#ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis
ff.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```